# How to prevent SQL injection in native insert query with JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, sql-injection

I'm using a native query with JPA / Hibernate to perform an insert or update ("upsert") on PostgreSQL, depending whether an object exists or not. The code looks like this:

```
val values: String = items.joinToString(", ", transform = this::convertItemToSqlValue)
val query = """
    insert into item (field1, field2)
    values $values
    on conflict on constraint item_pkey
    do update set 
        field1 = excluded.field1,
        field2 = excluded.field2
"""
entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate()
```

The function `convertItemToSqlValue` creates a String of the form `('value a', 123)`.

A positional parameter (`values ?`) didn't work (and led to a syntax error).

How could I prevent SQL injection with this kind of statmentement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building SQL statements from user input dynamically is not the best idea. It is better to use prepared statements. However there seems not be an easy way to perform patch updates with the JPA EntityManager in this case.

Setting multiple values is possible with JDBC. The following example show the usage with [Spring's JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html):

```
val items: List<Item> = ...

val statement = 
    """
    insert into item (field1, field2)
    values (?,?)
    on conflict on constraint arbeit_pkey
    do update set 
        field1 = excluded.field1,
        field2 = excluded.field2
    """
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
    statement, 
    object : BatchPreparedStatementSetter {
        override fun setValues(statement: PreparedStatement, index: Int) {
            val item = items[index]
            statement.setString(1, item.field1)
            statement.setInt(2, item.field2)
        }
        override fun getBatchSize(): Int = items.size
    }
)
```